VASP Molecular Dynamics Simulation
I want to study some physical properties of methane under high temperature and high density. However, when running molecular dynamics simulations, I noticed that the POTCAR pseudopotential file I used contains the PBE functional, while I considered the SCAN + rvv10 functional in the INCAR parameter settings. There was a warning given on the VASP log. I wonder whether this will actually affect the reliability of the results, as I am a novice in VASP simulation calculations.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

+1 but please make your title more clear and make it clear where your question is.

That is to say, the POTCAR I used contains the specified exchange-correlation functional PBE. However, when I was running the molecular dynamics simulation, the SCAN+Rvv10 functional was considered in the INCAR. Therefore, there was a warning in the log saying that differences were detected. I'd like to know whether this will affect the accuracy of the results.

Yes, this will affect the accuracy of your results, and in a way which is not easy to quantify. An early study of this kind was using LDA pseudopotentials with a GGA functional, which is now well-known to cause substantial errors: Fuchs et al, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.57.2134 . Is this what you wanted to know? If so, I can try to write it up as a proper answer later on.
